# Convert custom C++/Cuda layer to Pytorch/Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, caffe

I would like to use in a Pytorch model (or Tensorflow if it works better) a custom C++/CUDA Caffer layer. I don't know if there is a way to do it, or if I must reimplement the whole layer in Pytorch/Tensorflow. This is the repo that has a custom caffe implementation : https://github.com/MPI-IS/bilateralNN.

Thanks!

Comment: You might find [this tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_extension.html) useful